# Connecting to TFS with SOAP using C++

Tags: c++, web-services, soap, tfs

I have a C++ (QT5) application and now I wanted to connect to TFS and get the projects and few other details of the project. The main intention is to pull out the Test Cases from MTM.

So many examples using their API with C# and easily solving this problem. However I am having no such luck with C++. I am not sure how to proceed, should I write my own web service using the SDK and then use it or does TFS provide SOAP support.

I thought it did and hence fired fiddler to get to it, but never saw an auth method anywhere. All the requests I saw was GET. And there was a NTLM authorization as shown below.

```
GET http://localhost:8080/tfs HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/30.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Authorization: NTLM TlRMTVNTUAABAAAAB4IIogAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGAvAjAAAADw==
```

Any suggestions I can have or tips I would be grateful. I wish there was some documentation or samples/examples using C++.

If it has SOAP functions (WSDL) I could use KdSoap and use it with my application.

Thanks.

Comment: I saw just now that a new [REST API](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2014/05/12/a-new-api-for-visual-studio-online.aspx) has been released, but it looks like its for the online TFS. I am afraid I might have to write my own service consuming the TFS APIs. I wish somebody saves me here.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to bypass the API.

While you can connect to the web services for TFS directly there is no support for this method. Your code can break with any update to TFS. I would recommend that you create a web service with c# and then call that from your code. I would expect that the rest api's will become available on premises at some point.

Another option, although I am dubious of the support would be to create a hybrid DLL, C++ Managed, that can call the C# API's. You can then call the hybrid code from the native code. This is one extra level of wrapper and is really designed to help teams migrate from C++ to C#, but I believe that it will work.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI

Comment: Thanks @MrHinsh, I was afraid of this. I will leave this open though to see if I get some more replies..

Comment: Thanks again @MrHinsh I will explore this option too.

Comment: I am so lost here, and not able to work with it. Built a perfectly working C# application, connecting TFS and also getting all the test cases. If anybody could point me to an example please.